# Why is my href link returning a page that doesn't exist?

Tags: html

```
<A alt="Upload" href="http://ios0504e.idc.ikon.org:8020/OA_JAVA/test" target=new><STRONG>Upload</STRONG></A>
```

In the above mentioned tag, a file called as test.java is compiled and placed correctly and read, write, execute permissions are given. However, the link is not working. The alias for $OA_JAVA is also defined correctly.

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is. What goes wrong?

Comment: You said the file is called "**test.java**" and your linking to "**test**" only

Comment: link seems to be not existing ..........although the path exists in unix dir

Answer (score 0):

http://ios0504e.idc.ikon.org:8020/OA_JAVA/test or http://ios0504e.idc.ikon.org:8020/OA_JAVA/test.java seem to be invalid. With regards to the HTML block there is nothing wrong. Thus, the error is in the url you are trying to reach.

Comment: Do you have access to the path? You need to enable such that the path settings is such that it can be seen from the outside. If it as an apache server you need to chmod to suit your needs. I don't know anything about other webservers.

Comment: yeah i have access to path n i have set chmod 777.all permissions given

Answer (score 0):

This is how your a tag should look:
    **text**

As for your page, your server is down.

> Firefox can't find the server at ios0504e.idc.ikon.org

Comment: You need an extra carriage return after `look:` to get the code block to render correctly.